# Changing TextView color by selector tag

Tags: android

I have a `TextView`, I want to change its color by clicking it and save after exiting app, I used selector tag in a xml file in drawable folder but the problem is default color is right but nothing happens on click why?

Selector xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#FFA500"/>
<item android:color="#FF0000"/>
</selector>
```

`TextView` xml:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="Transferef Money"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@drawable/selector" />
```

Comment: `TextView view = new TextView(this);
        view.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);`

Comment: Have you setted the textview to be clickable?

Comment: you mean onClickListenner ?

Comment: Nop. 
TextView tv;
tv.setClickable(true);
Or via XML -> android:clickable="true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While color can be changed through a click handler

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
  textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
             textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
      } 
});
```

add an onClick attribute to your XML

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="Transferef Money"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@drawable/selector"
        android:onClick="colorise"
 />
```

and then set the color in `colorise` method.

Also, I don't think the state will be saved via an XML file, so you will have to handle it programitically.

Comment: I hve so many textviews I do not want to write this code for each of them

Comment: @AmirSadegh set up a method for this that uses the `TextView` as a parameter.

Comment: @AmirSadegh what, about a `for` loop, or use onClick inside XML

Comment: java method does not save new color either

Comment: @AmirSadegh wait I check it an post to you

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the `XML` completely and focus on it in your Java activity class:

```
TextView lbl = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
lbl.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        TextView lbl = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        lbl.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        lbl.setTextColor(Color.rgb(int, int, int));
        lbl.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have so many textviews in diffrent layouts, I do not want to write this code for each of them

Answer (score 0):

First define color in colors.xml, and use them in your selector, this works well for me.
Example:

```
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/blue_2"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/blue_2"/>
<item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/blue_2"/>
<item android:color="@color/black_1"/>
```

Comment: @isaiah .. will that save state after application exists ?

Comment: @AmirSadegh   In values/colors.xml:    <color name="white_1">#dddddd</color>
    <color name="white_2">#ffffff</color>

Comment: yeah, I want it to save new color

Comment: @twntee If you want to save the state after exist app, you could write  the state to the shared preferences, and reload the next time

Comment: @AmirSadegh save new color? when?

Comment: after clicking the text I want to save new color, how to do that?

Comment: @AmirSadegh Do you mean set new color to the text? you could call `textview.setTextColor`. If you want to save the color and reuse the next time the app start, you should save the color to shared peferences.